# problem with setting objects parameter in JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, geojson

I like to generate in JS array that will contain GeoJson objects with random values of coordinates.
I started with pushing 10 objects to array with loop and this part works but, when I like to set the random values of coordinates (so each object has different coordinates) I receive same coordinates for each object.

Is this some kind of passing by reference issue ? How to handle it?

My code looks like this:

```
//random number generator
function randomNumber(){
    min = Math.floor(0);
    max = Math.floor(360);
    let coordinateX = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
    let coordinateY = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
    return [coordinateX,coordinateY]
};
//geoJson object structure example
let featureClassObject = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [10,10] //these don't like to cooperate 
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}
//generating array and and pushing 10x GeoJson Object
let featuresArray = [];
for (let i=0;i<10;i++){
    featuresArray.push(featureClassObject);
}
//changing the value of coordinates 
featuresArray.forEach((item)=>{
    item.geometry.coordinates=randomNumber();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Object.assign() to make copies of the nested objects so you're not just referencing a pointer:

```
function randomNumber(){
    min = Math.floor(0);
    max = Math.floor(360);
    let coordinateX = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
    let coordinateY = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
    return [coordinateX,coordinateY]
};
//geoJson object structure example
let featureClassObject = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [10,10]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}
//generating array and and pushing 10x GeoJson Object
let featuresArray = [];
for (let i=0;i<10;i++){
    featureClassCopy = Object.assign({}, featureClassObject);
    featureClassCopy.geometry = Object.assign({}, featureClassCopy.geometry);
    featuresArray.push(featureClassCopy);
}
//changing the value of coordinates 
featuresArray.forEach((item)=>{
    item.geometry.coordinates=randomNumber();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the same object 10 times. You can fix this easily by using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
const featuresArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    featuresArray.push(Object.assign({}, featureClassObject));
}
```

This pushes 10 different objects containing the same data.

Answer (score 0):

So generally, the above was a kind of passing by reference issue.
How to check it?

```
array[0]===array[1]
```

when above returns true it means that you have created a number of reference to one object inside of your array.

To handle it, there is one way -> you have to copy an object before pushing it to the array.
**There are two few ways of copying objects**:
 **1. Shallow copying** (does not copy nested parts of objects and for nested part of object still returns reference):
        - `let copyOfObjectFirstWay = Object.assign({}, objectName);`
        - `let copyOfObjectSecondWay = {...objectName}`;
 **2. Deep copying** (copies whole even the nested part):
        - `let copyOfObjectDeepWay = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectName));` - this may cause some perfomance issue when objects are big&complex.

In my case (tanks to hint from Seanonymous) I solve it by making object generator function that returns copy of an object (parsed&stringified). 
My code

```
function randomNumber(min, max){
    let random = ((Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min).toFixed(4);
    return random
};

function objectGenerator(){
    let featureClassObject = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [10,10]
        },
       "properties": {
            "name": "Dinagat Islands"
        }
    };
    featureClassObject.geometry.coordinates=[randomNumber(20.13666, 21.875), 
    randomNumber(51.87,52.3160)];
    let newFeatureClassObcject= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(featureClassObject));
    return newFeatureClassObcject;
};

let randomFeatureClassArray= [];
function randomGeometryObjectArrayGenerator(){
    let t0=performance.now();

for (let i=0;i<100;i++){
    randomFeatureClassArray.push(objectGenerator());
};
let t1=performance.now();
console.log(`the array was generated in  ${t1-t0} miliseconds`)
};

randomGeometryObjectArrayGenerator();
```